# Preload an array of jpegs for UIViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm making a full screen animation based on pan gesture. Basically I have an array of UIImages, and when a the user pans, I'm changing an image to a corresponding from this array, based on the coordinate of the finger on screen.
THe problem is, apparently because of the loading, the animation is really slow, when panning the first time. As soon as I pan through every possible image, it starts to be ok.
Is there any way to preload the images. Or am I doing something conceptually wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure exactly what you are doing, but if your pictures are in some order, and you know when the user pans next, what picture will show, you can load the picture before the user pans...that should fix your loading issues...

Hope it helps

Daniel

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. However I can't predict the users' pans. Basically I have an object that moves from on screen side to another. And I'm trying to make the animation of this movement follow the finger.

Comment: I mean if one goes before another etc, u can predict which will come next, even if it's more than a few possibilities